# React native projects not running in IOS

Tags: ruby, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods, ios15

This is my error coming when I'm running the project in IOS 15 devices. It's not installing pod(pod install), I tried too many things but still I can't get any solution.

```
englishmuni@Englishs-Mac-mini ios % pod install
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9: from /Users/englishmuni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
        8: from /Users/englishmuni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
        7: from /Users/englishmuni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
        6: from /Users/englishmuni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        5: from /Users/englishmuni/Documents/Project/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
        4: from /Users/englishmuni/Documents/Project/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/bin/pod:36:in `require'
        3: from /Users/englishmuni/Documents/Project/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /Users/englishmuni/Documents/Project/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `require'
        1: from /Users/englishmuni/Documents/Project/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/englishmuni/Documents/Project/AwesomeProject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:108:in `<class:Array>': undefined method `deprecator' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  deprecate_constant
englishmuni@Englishs-Mac-mini ios %
```

Here is my error when I'm running the project in IOS emulator,

```
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project AwesomeProject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme AwesomeProject -destination id=3CFEB6FE-7545-4BB9-BFAD-177A0CF3DE2C

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (1 target)
    Target 'AwesomeProject' in project 'AwesomeProject' (no dependencies)

GatherProvisioningInputs

CreateBuildDescription
```

Comment: Which version of cocoapods do you have? And how did you install it, through homebrew?

Answer (score 1):

There is chance to have incompatibility issues with the ruby version.

Check the versions of the [Ruby gem file](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/), [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/), [bundler](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-update.1.html), and update if needed.